# Set Multiple Role Angular js

Tags: angularjs

how to set multiple role in angular.js **$routeProvider**

```
config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/dashboard.html',
            controller: "DashboardCtrl"

        })

            .when("/readmyforms", {
                templateUrl: "Views/ReadMyForms.html",
                controller: "readmyforms",
                role: "admin"

            })
}
```

i want to set multiple role here

`role: "admin"` and `role: "manager"`

Answer (score 0):

Add a constant service for roles

```
.constant('USER_ROLES', {
    Manager:'Manager',
    Admin:'Admin'
});
```

Add a data variable in $routeProvider and pass the roles as authorizedRoles

```
data: {
  authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.Manager, USER_ROLES.Admin]
}
```

And use `$routeChangeStart` action to know which user is allowed on login.
Hope this helps.